# Why does this class freeze the program?

Tags: c++, class, freeze, void

This class should read some lines from a data and from them to variables which i can use in further operations. but for some reason it freezes if it detected the data and try to load it. why?
i can't see my mistake hope u can help me.

btw: the strange language which is used in the class is german^^ hope this doesn't matter.

```
void Kunde::laden(){
        string inhalt_anrede, inhalt_vname, inhalt_nname, inhalt_knummer, inhalt_pin, inhalt_guthaben;
        int anrede, vorname, nachname, knummer, pin, guthaben;

        system("cls");
        cout << "wie ist ihr nachname?" << endl;
        cin  >> nname;

        user1.open(nname, ios::in);

        if(!user1.is_open()){
            cout << "Datei nicht gefunden" << endl;
        }

        if(user1.is_open()){

         for ( int anrede=0;!user1.eof();anrede++){
             if (anrede==1){
                 getline(user1, inhalt_anrede);       
                 strcpy(Anrede,inhalt_anrede.c_str());
             }
         }
         for ( int vorname=0;!user1.eof();vorname++){
             if (vorname==2){
                 strcpy(vname,inhalt_vname.c_str());
             }
         }
         for ( int nachname=0;!user1.eof();nachname++){
             if (nachname==3){
                 getline(user1, inhalt_nname);       
                 strcpy(nname,inhalt_nname.c_str());
             }
         }
         for ( int knummer=0;!user1.eof();knummer++){
             if (knummer==4){
                 getline(user1, inhalt_knummer);       
                 echte_kontonummer=atol(inhalt_knummer.c_str());
             }
         }
         for ( int pin=0;!user1.eof();pin++){
             if (pin==5){
                 getline(user1, inhalt_pin);       
                 echte_pin=atoi(inhalt_pin.c_str());
             }
         }
         for ( int guthaben=0;!user1.eof();guthaben++){
             if (guthaben==6){
                 getline(user1, inhalt_guthaben);       
                 Guthaben=atoi(inhalt_guthaben.c_str());
             }
         }
         cout << "Daten erfolgreich geladen." << endl;

         }
         user1.close();
    }
```

I will explain the structer of one loop with an example

```
     for ( int guthaben=0;!user1.eof();guthaben++){ //i think this is understandable
         if (guthaben==6){ //in this case the desired value is on line 6
             getline(user1, inhalt_guthaben);       
             Guthaben=atoi(inhalt_guthaben.c_str()); //from string to int to the desired value Guthaben.
         }
     }
```

hope u can help me.

Comment: please dont use !user1.eof(); in a for :(, also I dont think you need that many loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see in your loop is, that you don't read any line if you are not at the line you want to be at. But as you don't read any line, you will not get further to the line you want to read. That does not only prevent you from reaching the line you actually want to read, but also from reaching the eof in acceptable time (you will, after `guthaben` was overflowed as many times as you have lines in your file). So what you have to do is read the line in all circumstances and discard the value if you don't need it.
Try:

```
for ( int guthaben=0;!user1.eof();guthaben++){ //i think this is understandable
         if (guthaben==6){ //in this case the desired value is on line 6
             getline(user1, inhalt_guthaben);       
             Guthaben=atoi(inhalt_guthaben.c_str()); //from string to int to the desired value Guthaben.
         }else
             getline(user1, inhalt_guthaben);
     }
```

or

```
for ( int guthaben=0;!user1.eof();guthaben++){ //i think this is understandable
             getline(user1, inhalt_guthaben);       
        if (guthaben==6){ //in this case the desired value is on line 6
             Guthaben=atoi(inhalt_guthaben.c_str()); //from string to int to the desired value Guthaben.
          }
     }
```

Note that this will lead to issues with your current style of reading. it would be better to have everything in one loop, as e.James suggested:

```
for ( int zeile=1;!user1.eof();zeile++){//Natural counting (beginning at 1)!
    std::string inhalt;
    getline(user1, inhalt);
    switch(zeile){
             case 1:
                strcpy(Anrede,inhalt.c_str());
             break;
             case 2:
                 strcpy(vname,inhalt.c_str());
             break;
             case 3:
                 strcpy(nname,inhalt.c_str());
             break;
             case 4:
                 echte_kontonummer=atol(inhalt.c_str());
             break;
             case 5:
                 echte_pin=atoi(inhalt.c_str());
             break;
             case 6:
                 Guthaben=atoi(inhalt.c_str());
             break;
         }
}
```

Also note that it is very bad style to have the variables `Guthaben` and `guthaben` which can be confused easily (if they aren't already). I would suggest to you that you rename `guthaben` to `zeile` because it defines on which line you want to read.

Comment: thank u i do not realy understand why but it works! thanks oh and because the upper and lowercase. i find it much more confusing if i have 20.000 of different variables. but i think everyone has his own style

Comment: @globus243: You only read a line if you are at line 6 in your example. But as you presumably want to discard the lines before you have to read them of the buffer. Worse you might have more then one line in your file which will result in an (nearly) endless loop because you will read only when `guthaben == 6` so you wont proceed to the end of the file.

Comment: @globus243: Added another example as I think the suggestion I made before will not work together with your full code unless you rewind the stream after each loop.

Answer (score 2):

You only read a line if `guthaben` is `6` - else you spin indefinitely (until `eof` - which may not be the case). For all other values of `guthaben`, you are not consuming from the stream `user1` - so how do you expect to hit `eof`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mix of C and C++, but that is not (necessarily) a problem. The main problem is the way you are handling the file input loop. As a supplement to the already posted answers, here is a C++ loop which should do what you want:

```
std::string anrede;
std::string vorname;
...
for (int line_number=0; input_file.good(); line_number++){
    getline(input_file, input_line);
    if (line_number==1) { anrede = input_line; }
    if (line_number==2) { vorname = input_line; }
    ...
}
```